# aggregating column values oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a result set like so:

```
STAFF_NUM   FLEET_CD    EFF_DT  
00046110    320         25-NOV-74 00:00 
00046110    330         25-NOV-74 00:00 
00046110    737         16-JAN-15 00:00 
00046110    767         25-NOV-74 00:00 
00046110    777         07-FEB-14 00:00 
00046110    IL9         25-NOV-74 00:00 
00046110    SU9         25-NOV-74 00:00
```

Is there an aggregate function that will allow me to group/transform this into a single row, like this?

```
STAFF_NUM   Fleets
00046110    320, 330, 737, 767, 777, IL9, SU9
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT STAFF_NUM ,
       LISTAGG(FLEET_CD , ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY EFF_DT ) "Fleets"
  FROM t
  GROUP BY STAFF_NUM
```